# How to get a nested object in a document of Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a document design as below:

```
Document[IgaSZRSo8viqK9VxpJ6H]:
name:David
type:1
proList:
    item1:
        name:apple
        price:1
    item2:
        name:grape
        price:1
    item3:
        name:orange
        price:2
amount:
    basic:10
    extra:20
```

Everything goes perfectly when uploading to firestore, but when I download the date from firestore, I always get the exception "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference" when I type as:
**proList.item1.name**

I can get all information include **amount.basic** and **amount.extra** without any error!

I don't know why and cannot find any information in official docs.

**EDIT**

Below are the structure in Java:

taskEntity.java:

```
public class TaskEntity{
    public String name, type;
    public proListEntity;
    public amountEntity;

    public TaskEntity(){

    }
    public void set(TaskEntity entity){
    this.name=entity.name;
    this.type=entity.type;
    this.proListEntity=entity.proListEntity;
    this.amountEntity=entity.amountEntity;
    }
}
```

proListEntity.java

```
public class proListEntity{
    public String name;
    public long price;


    public proListEntity(){

    }
    public void set(proListEntity entity){
    this.name=entity.name;
    this.price=entity.price;
    }
}
```

Download the data from firestore:

```
TaskEntity mEntity = documentSnapshot.toObject(TaskEntity.class);
```

Comment: Please upload the method which stores the data to firestore. So we can evalute how you are storing it in first place.

Comment: @Dhaval, I have updated my code.

Comment: May be what you need is following. 
TaskEntitiy should be stored in collection. And ProListEntitiy should be stored as sub-collection in each document of TaskEntity.
Otherwise, ProListEntity could be a list in TaskEntity document.

Comment: Please add the entire code that you are using to get the data from the database, please also add your database structure as a screenshot  and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for your reply. I have already fiixed it with modifying the structure which was mentioned by Dhaval -- stored as sub-collection in each document